# How can I expose kubernetes services from within a local VM?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running kubernetes locally in a guest VM. How can I expose services to the host?

On GKE, for example, exposing a service requisitions an IP from Google and wires it up, so that requests to that IP end up at the right service. How can I do that for my VM?

Answer (score 2):

Not the wanted answer but you have to do it manually for now. I usually start a nginx container with `--net=host` to proxy from kubernetes network to VM network.

I hope to be wrong but it was true some month ago.

Comment: Ah, yeargh! Thanks for the workaround. I'll hope for a better answer to be true and then accept this in a while ;)